# Como funciona e onde se utiliza Bag of Words?

Tags: inteligência-artificial

Recentemente tenho pesquisado sobre inteligência artificial e achei alguns artigos falando de um tal "bag of words", mas não sei o que é e não achei nada em português falando sobre isso.

Gostaria de saber, o que é o tal "bag of words", e em quais casos ele se aplica? Se possivel, deixe as fontes.

Comment: `bag` é um conceito matemático. Algo mais ou menos como `conjunto, porém pode repetir elementos e ignora ordenação`

Comment: Tem algum desses artigos com link fácil para ajudar a contextualizar o uso desse `bag`?

Comment: Infelizmente não :/

Comment: Não entendi direito sua explicação, poderia dar exemplos de casos que se aplicam? @JeffersonQuesado

Comment: Conjuntos: `{0, 1, 2} U {2, 4} = {0, 1, 2, 4}`; _bags_: `{0, 1, 2} U {2, 4} = {0, 1, 2, 2, 4}`; também _bags_: `{0, 1, 3, 1, 2} - {0, 1} = {3, 1, 2}`

Comment: Para aplicações no mundo real, vide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_(mathematics)?wprov=sfsi1

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Legal, obrigado por me mostrar um caminho. Parece ter sim uma relação com o termo "bag of words", mas ainda não é o que eu queria.

Comment: Google Acadêmico retorna algo para "bag of words"?

Comment: Sem querer achei isso: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model; parece relevante

Comment: Parece que a terceira seção desse relatório descreve algo sobre "bag of words": http://conteudo.icmc.usp.br/CMS/Arquivos/arquivos_enviados/BIBLIOTECA_113_RT_209.pdf

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não sabia que existia esse Google Acadêmico, lol. Esse Wikipedia tem algumas coisas interessantes, mas ainda não achei o que eu queria...

Comment: o relatório técnico que eu enviei o link depôs do link da Wiki, foi mais direto ao assunto? Lá ele fala em classificação de documentos e PLN usando "bag of words", inclusive tem uma tabela lá de uns documentos de exemplo com as palavras "cas", "filh" e outras

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Acho que consegui chegar onde eu queria, publiquei uma resposta, acho que ilustra bem o assunto.

Comment: boa resposta =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Explicação

O modelo *bag-of-words* é uma representação simplificada usada no [processamento de linguagem natural](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processamento_de_linguagem_natural) e na [recuperação de informações (IR)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recupera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Neste modelo, um texto (como uma frase ou um documento) é representado como o saco (multiset) de suas palavras, desconsiderando a gramática e mesmo a ordem das palavras, mas mantendo a multiplicidade.

## Exemplo de Implementação

Os seguintes modelos são um documento de texto usando *bag-of-words*.

Aqui estão dois documentos de texto simples:

```
(1) John gosta de assistir filmes. Mary também gosta de filmes.

(2) John também gosta de assistir jogos de futebol.
```

Com base nesses dois documentos de texto, uma lista é construída da seguinte forma:

```
[ 
    "John" , 
    "gosta" , 
    "de" , 
    "assistir" , 
    "filmes" , 
    "Mary" , 
    "também" , 
    "futebol" , 
    "jogos" 
]
```

Também é comum calcular a frequência de aparecimento das palavras:

```
linear(tj) = 1 − d(tj)/N
```

Onde `tj` é a palavra que deseja encontrar a frequência, `d(tj)` a quantidade de vezes em que a palavra aparece e `N` é a quantidade de documentos ou frases.

## Conclusão

De forma simples, o *bag-of-words* é uma forma de representação de texto. E comumente é usado para [machine learning](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprendizado_de_m%C3%A1quina), [sentiment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis), [chatbot](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterbot) e [topic model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model).

*Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)*